# Is it safe to delete the /module folder?

Tags: 8, composer

I see that the /module folder still exists and a /module/contrib folder has the updated module folders in it.

> [image: after composerize]

- `composer update` has updated the site to **8.9**
- `composer update` will not update any of the modules still shown in /modules (webform for example)
- When running `composer update`, Composer reports installing *Webform 8.5.16*, but it doesn't in fact install it and the site still reports *Webform 8.x-5.4-beta1*

  - Many other modules are also not updating
  - The modules in /module are the old versions, while the newer versions are in /module/contrib
  - Drupal think the modules are in the old path (for example, /module/webform)

What is the safest way to fix the problem?
Delete folders in /module folder other than contrib and rerun composer update?

I have already executed the following commands.

1. `composer composerize`
2. `composer cc`
3. `composer self-update`
4. `sudo rm -Rf composer.lock vendor/`
5. `composer update`

Comment: have you tried drush updb ?
after deleting modules in modules folder ?

Comment: Looks as if there are custom module in there in the modules/custom/ folder. They need to be put pack there. And all contrib modules should be placed inside modules/contrib/.

Comment: When I deleted the /modules/webform folder, the site went to white screen with errors.  Then I copied the new webform folder from /modules/contrib/webform to /modules/webform and the site works and is at ver 5.16.  Composer doesn't effect that location however. This is on my dev site.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to delete the versions of the modules directly under /modules, and clear cache; in theory that should be enough to get the system to re-register the same modules from their new locations.

Take a backup of the files and database first, and if you want to play it safe, delete one module folder at a time, running `drush cr` and checking that the version Drupal now sees is correct after each deletion.

It's probably wise to run `drush updb` after this, in case any of module versions have incremented and there are updates.

Comment: And you should try this on a non-live environment first. I think that's obvious, but in case it's not.

Comment: I am using composer only.  I used extend/uninstall on admin_toolbar then refreshed and saw /modules/admin_toolbar was gone.  I then went to site and checked/installed module.  The version was the new one at /modules/contrib/admin_toolbar.  Doing this procedure with webform, flag, feed etc is worrisome.  Thus, the question

Comment: After installing drush and running drush cr.... everything worked